# Firefox and Safari show different button styles

Tags: html, css

I have created a CSS button on my site and validated the design via Google Chrome.

I used the following designs:

```
.btn-kabumm {
    background-color: #87cbac;
    color: #fff;
    border-color: #87cbac; 
}

.btn-lg {
    padding: 10px 16px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1.3333333;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
```

However, in Safari and FF the button gets a weird extra border.

Chrome:

[image]

Firefox/Safari:

[image]

I am not quite sure how to get rid of that though.

Comment: Do you use css reset? https://css-tricks.com/reboot-resets-reasoning/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you forgot to give your button the bootstrap root `btn` class that all buttons are meant to have, see the documentation on bootstrap buttons [here](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#buttons)

EG:

```
<input id="nf-field-9" value="Absenden" class="ninja-forms-field btn btn-kabumm btn-lg btn-rounded nf-element" type="button">
```

is how it should be, but you had

```
<input id="nf-field-9" value="Absenden" class="ninja-forms-field btn-kabumm btn-lg btn-rounded nf-element" type="button">
```

Compare the code with the button in your carousel, and you'll see that's the difference between the two

Adding the proper class results in this:

[image]

Screenshot taken on Firefox v58.0b3 (64-bit) on Linux :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add all properties to the bordered element. 
Border-style. Border Width etc for example

```
 .item{
Border: 1px solid transparent; 
}
```

Probably safari has some default border styling so forcing IT by yourself you can resolve this issue.

Answer (score -1):

Just add `border:none;` to your css it will force chrome to hide his predefined style for the button input

Comment: The issue isn't with chrome, OP says it renders right on chrome, but doesn't work as it should on firefox and safari