# Bootstrap 4 Select on Safari not the same

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, safari

I'm using bootstrap 4, and on my Safari on my mac the dropdown looks like this

[image]

Which looks different from the `input` on the left of it. On other browsers like chrome and firefox the input and select look the same.

This is my dropdown HTML in my `form`

```
<div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 form-group">
            

<input type="text" id="data-product" class="form-control border-0 form-control-lg shadow" name="Data[product]" maxlength="17" placeholder="Enter Product">

<div class="invalid-feedback"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 form-group">
        

<select id="data-data_from" class="form-control border-0 form-control-lg shadow" name="Data[data_from]">
<option value="" selected="" disabled="">Country</option>
<option value="jp" data-title="Japan">Japan</option>
<option value="us" data-title="USA">U.S.A</option>
</select>

<div class="invalid-feedback"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block shadow"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>        </div>
    </div>
```

How do i style it the same on Safari? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Bootstrap 4, try and use `custom-select custom-select-lg` instead of `form-control form-control-lg`

```
   <select id="data-data_from" class="custom-select custom-select-lg border-0 shadow" name="Data[data_from]">
    <option value="" selected="" disabled="">Country</option>
    <option value="jp" data-title="Japan">Japan</option>
    <option value="us" data-title="USA">U.S.A</option>
    </select>
```

More about **Custom-forms** here
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#custom-forms

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the following to your CSS

`select {-webkit-appearance:none;}`

This also works for Bootstrap 5

Comment: simple and very clear.
should be accepted as an answer.
thx.

Comment: This method works but has no dropdown arrow (as it is telling the browser not to render the normal control)

Answer (score 0):

I think that happens because of Mac, i tried on both operating systems, and its the same for me.

Maybe try `style="background-color:#fff"`, maybe that helps, but idk more than that sorry.

[Maybe this link helps you, good luck :)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079206/firefox-and-safari-show-different-button-styles/48079333)

Answer (score 0):

You can achive consisent look across browsers if you use Bootstrap Dropdown:

```
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button
            class="btn dropdown-toggle shadow btn-lg"
            type="button"
            id="dropdownMenuButton"
            data-toggle="dropdown"
            aria-expanded="false"
          >
            Country
          </button>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Japan</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">USA</a>
          </div>
        </div>
```

It will look like this in Safari (and the same in other browsers):

[image: Safari screenshot]

But, this is a different element and so you need to work with its data differently than with `<select>`

Comment: would that work for in a form? plus after you select the country don't think it would show as selected right?

Comment: No, it would not show as selected (unless you write some code to change the button contents dynamically). This is a different element with different behavior.